# How do I store data and create a real time graph on a website?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services

I'm struggling mightily with figuring out how to create an online graph (I'm not a web developer at all).

So, I have this python code that I've created to to synthesize a bunch of information about stock prices and then come up with a number. So I run it, and it spits out 47 for example based on all the data I've collected.

I'd like to have this run every 5 minutes, store the data somewhere, and then create a graph on a basic website. I have absolutely no idea where to start here, as my web dev experience is pretty limited. Can program html/css, that's about it. Have stayed pretty solely in the world of limited python, data science and jupyter notebooks.

Looking for some resources/a track as my google has failed me. I'm getting a lot of information here, without a way to figure out the best approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues

Answer (score 0):

So some things you could look into or do is use a  javascript library for charts like [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), Chartists.js, or a mulitude of other options. [Chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/). These libaries take JSON and use that data to turn it into a multitude of different graphs. If you need help start, I hope this gives you some guidance [Python Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gviz_api_lib). Some of the links on these pages should help shed some light on your issues and give you some guidance.